# How to reset items in radio button list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

Easy one.

I added programatically a few items to a radiuo button list:

```
foreach (var item in res)
{
     rbl.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.text, item.value.ToString()));
}
```

After a change of view (Multiview), I need to come back to the view with the radio button list, but this view added again the items.

How can I reset the items already added to the radio button list?

Used, and not working:

```
rbl.ClearSelection()

rbl.Datasource = null;
rbl.DataBind();

rbl = new RadioButtonList();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "ClearSelection()" method simply puts the selection to be "-1", in order to remove the data in the list you will need

```
RadioButtonList1.Items.Clear();
```

Also be careful, where you actually add the items, that might cause a problem as well, since I cannot see additional code it is just my prediction.

Hope this solves your problem.
Cheers!

Comment: Piece of cake, Thanks @PetarStojanovski